# How to prevent from text to extend the <li> container height?

Tags: css

[My code - Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QySxLfThkDDV7d0CAtFM?p=preview)

I try to create a fluid layout, my sidebar is made of a list of links. I want each `<li>` element to be a perfect square, the problem starts when I add the text inside. It seems to be adding height to my square and what I get is a rectangle. If you examine my code the dimensions of my list `objects` are 
32px X 43px. How can I prevent from an inside text to extend the `<li>` elements?
And how can I make the text appear on the bottom left side of the `<li>` element?

My CSS:

```
body{
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0 auto;
 }

 .content {
    width: 95%;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
  }  

  .sidebar{
      width: 5%;
      display: inline;
      float: left;
   }

 .sidebar ul{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    list-style: none;

  }

 .sidebar li{
    padding: 50%;
    background-color: oldlace;
  }

  .sidebar a{
    display: block;
    font-size: 0.5em;
  }
```

My HTML:

```
 <body >
<h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>

<div class="sidebar">
  <ul>
        <li><a href="#">ANALYTICS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">STYLES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">VOTERS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">GET STARTED</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">UPDATE</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <p>Blahahhhahhhahahahahahahhahahah blahahahh bluah</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried `word-wrap`?

Comment: I added the code, and yes I tried word-wrap it seems to make the problem worse.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish. By looking at the CSS, it's not specifying a height, so if you add a text inside the square, it will increase the height by whatever size text you've added in there, no? Why not "height:32px; width:32px; overflow:hidden;"?

Comment: Also, your sidebar is awfully narrow on small screens.

Comment: I'm trying to implement a liquid layout, so I don't specify `px` units only percentage. By using `padding: 50%` It is making the `<li>` a prefect square the 32px is window dependent. Anyway what ruins the perfect square is the text, it adds more px to the height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `position: relative` on the `li` and `position: absolute` on the `a`.  Using `absolute` will cause the `a` element to not affect the `li`'s dimensions.  In this way you can also position it in the corner.

http://plnkr.co/edit/kcjCl1?p=preview

```
.sidebar li{
      padding: 50%;
      position: relative;
}

.sidebar a{
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Why did you use `position: relative`?

Comment: So that the `a` elements are positioned relative to the `li` they are contained in, instead of relative to the whole document.  That is why `bottom: 0` and `left: 0` put the element in the corner of the `li` instead of the corner of the document.